# How to do a "tree walk" recursively on an Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: python, recursion

Simple example of assignment in my language:

```
x = 3 ->
```

Here's the generated AST after parsing (In Python):

```
[('statement', ('assignment', 'x', ('assignment_operator', '='), ('expr', ('term', ('factor', '3')))), '->')]
```

How can I recursively access any possible depth in order to, in the most trivial case, print all of them? (Or convert the text into something else?). Is there a specific algorithm for doing this? If there is, do you recommend any specific material?

Comment: Why not just use the `ast` module functionality? [`ast.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.walk) for example.

Comment: I had no idea of the existence of such module. I only knew about os.walk() (Which is specific for directories).

Comment: Well, it may be that that module is too specific to the Python grammar; if you have your own grammar the module is probably not suitable.

Comment: I do have [my own grammar](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Lilith). I was trying to interpret everything at each parse rule function from YACC, and as it grew in complexity (Such as condition blocks), I've learned that I need to generate an AST and later interpret / translate the code from it.

Comment: The structure of your tuples are not entirely clear to me; I made an assumption that everything but the  first element are children, but you may want to formalise the contents a little.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To walk a tree, just use a stack or a queue (depending on wether you want to go depth first or breath first).

For each node encountered, push the children onto the stack or into the queue, then take the next item out of the data structure to process and repeat.

For example, breath first could look like this:

```
from collections import deque

def walk(node):
    queue = deque([node])
    while queue:
        node = queue.popleft()
        if isinstance(node, tuple):
            queue.extend(node[1:])  # add the children to the queue
        yield node
```

which produces the following walking order for your tree:

```
>>> for node in walk(tree[0]):
...     print(node[0] if isinstance(node, tuple) else node)
...
statement
assignment
->
x
assignment_operator
expr
=
term
factor
3
```

Your data structure is a little messy, mixing tuples of different length. You may want to look to using a [`nametuple` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to formalise the contents a little.

Comment: The nametuple class is a hell of a good idea. Thank you very much! It'll certainly help me (Especially when the language becomes more nightmarish to interpret).

Comment: @EricsonWillians: you may want to [study the `ast` module source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ast.py); Python uses custom classes per node type but the module helper functions and classes should be of help in any AST processing.